# how to close eclipse timely compile?

Tags: java, eclipse

for example, I'm coding in java with eclipse,  when I make a syntax error, eclipse will report it ,like this :
![enter image description here][1]

After a long time ,I become rely on the timely compile ,result in low code speed, So ,I want to close the timely compile and I will be care when coding . So, how ,how to close the compile tip ?

Comment: Seems to me you want to disable syntax check, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to disable eclipse timely compile  :

1. Click on Preferences menu item.
2. Type in the search box "Editor" and select "Java" as parent in tree.
3. Uncheck the **Report problems as you type**.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want ~ @Kuldeep Mahajan